# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' Try defining the operator '[]' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set,

`ListView.builder's itemcount` to firebase's users collection's group(field) list length
(You can see it below image)

my try below image

[image]

my try:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final isCollectionEmpty = snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty;
            final DocumentsWhichContainsPosts = snapshot.data!.docs.where(
                (doc) =>
                    (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["groups"].isNotEmpty);
            if (DocumentsWhichContainsPosts.isNotEmpty) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!['groups'].length, // this shows error
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return Text("data");
                }),
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text("No posts")),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red),
            );
          }
        });
```

When this code run, showing this error

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' Try defining the operator '[]'

Comment: `data` is a function, so `snapshot.data()!` instead of `snapshot.data!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!['groups'].length, // this shows error
```

This shows an error because `snapshot.data` here is a `QuerySnapshot`, which doesn't have an `[]` operation. If you want to return the number of documents in the `QuerySnapshot`, use:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
```

And then in the item builder, you can get data from each document with:

```
itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
  return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]("groups").length);
}),
```